# how to set pi and use it for converting area of a square on batch file

Tags: batch-file

it wont read the values with decimal

```
@echo off

echo Area of a Square

echo Enter the radius of a circle:

set /p rad=

set pi=3.14159

set /a area=%pi%*%rad%*%rad%

echo The area of a Square is: %area%

pause>nul
```

Comment: An option to work around the 32-bit signed integer limitation was to specify PI as integer like `314159` (so it's actually PI * 10^4), then doing the calculation (given that radius is an integer value and PI * 10^4 * radius^2 does not exceed the limit 2^31 - 1), then inserting the `.` in front of the last 4 figures by string operations (so the radius is limited to 82; using a digit less for PI like `31416` allows radii up to 261, etc.)...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **I don't think there is a simple way** to calculate numbers with decimals using only pure batch only, **but it is still possible** to use WScript inside of batch scripts. I found a very useful function [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27624272/Using-decimals-in-maths-calculations-in-BATCH.html). I modified it just a bit so it can be more practical.

```
:Eval [expression]
  echo Wscript.Echo Eval(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))>"%~dp0eval.vbs"
  for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('cscript //nologo eval.vbs "%~1"') do set eval=%%A
  if exist "%~dp0eval.vbs" del "%~dp0eval.vbs"
  exit /b
```

It can be used to "Eval" some WScript code directly in your batch scripts.

---

Here I incorporated this function in your script and it seems to be working perfectly. If you want more decimals for the result, you need to change the second parameter of the "Round" function.

```
@echo off

echo Area of a Square

echo Enter the radius of a circle:

set /p rad=

set pi=3.14159

:: set /a area=pi*rad*rad

call :Eval "round(%pi%*%rad%*%rad%, 2)"
set area=%Eval%

echo The area of a Square is: %area%

pause & exit /b

:Eval [expression]
  echo Wscript.Echo Eval(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))>"%~dp0eval.vbs"
  for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('cscript //nologo eval.vbs "%~1"') do set eval=%%A
  if exist "%~dp0eval.vbs" del "%~dp0eval.vbs"
  exit /b
```

---

Not super important but just for your information, when you set a variable you don't need to use % around your variable.
Example:

```
set /a area=pi*rad*rad
```

---

Like SteveFest pointed out in the comment section, it's possible to use a Batch script with a downloadable math library that will be **"Emulating pen and paper calculations."** In my opinion it's a bit overkill for this question, but you can choose the solution that is better for you.

Comment: This contains faulty information - the percentage signs can be there, and will not cause a difference.

Comment: I never said they cannot be there, I said "you don't need to use them". Very simple english...

Comment: Ok. But the "Correction" and "instead off" part can be dismissed? Cause "Correction" does cause people to think that %'s mustn't be here

Comment: **Is is possible** One can simulate pen calculations, step by step even when it contains decimal, **just remove the decimal point**

Comment: Ok, interesting... I will modify my answer accordingly but I will still let my script/function there just in case someone prefer this method. The more options you have the better it is.